# High performance nearest neighbor search with moving neighbors

Tags: python, algorithm

Given 10,000 64-dimensional vectors and I need to find the vector with the least euclidean distance to an arbitrary point.

The tricky part is that these 10,000 vectors move. Most of the algorithms I have seen assume stationary points and thus can make good use of indexes. I imagine it will be too expensive to rebuild indexes on every timestep.

Below is the pseudo code.

```
for timestep in range(100000):
    data = get_new_input()
    nn = find_nearest_neighbor(data)
    nn.move_towards(data)
```

One thing to note is that the vectors only move a little bit on each timestep, about 1%-5%. One non-optimal solution is to rebuild indexes every ~1000 timesteps. It is OK if the nearest neighbor is approximate. Maybe using each vectors momentum would be useful?

I am wondering what is the best algorithm to use in this scenario?

Comment: Have you considered kd-tree ?